# How to simulate production concurrency issue using tests

Tags: testing, concurrency

I've have an application which receives an object from queue, transforms it and publishes it on a topic. It's a message driven bean (spring) message listener container with a fair number of inner beans.

Some strange activity recently happened on the prod boxes. We want to check if this is a concurrency issue. Which is great, but not something I've done before.

My approach is to pump a load of messages at application. Write a piece of software to listen to it's publishing topic. Consume these and process them via something similar to Junit tests which compares the objects attributes with the expected result.

I've added the above for a bit of scope on the problem but basically is there any applications on the market that I could plug into either my code or my IDE which would enable me to do that. I think this is somewhat over the capabilities for JUNIT

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [JavaPathfinder (JPF)](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf) for this type of exercise.

`JPF` is essentially a JVM that simulates execution of your code in every possible way - e.g. simulating all the possible interleavings of the bytecode instructions. JPF works as a `model checker` that explores the set of possible states that an application can enter and evaluates them based on predefined rules -e.g. `deadlock free`, `non-null`, etc.

Model checkers usually fail when applications become too complex but JPF is able to execute the app without traversing the whole state space and is usually able to reach problem states pretty quickly. Try to have a look at that one.